# How do I fix the layering of my Navbar and Banner?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

I'm using React & Tailwind, and I'm currently working on my `Navbar` and Banner.

As you can see from the photos below, although my page looks fine stylistically, I can't hover/click on my `Events` and `Merch` links in the `Navbar` because the 'Mahjong Social' text is layered on top.

I've tried using `z-index` on my `Navbar`, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. What's the best way to fix this problem?

Thank you,

**Navbar.js**

```
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="flex justify-around items-center w-2/3 mx-auto my-2 bg-green-800 rounded-md border-solid border-2 z-50">
        <a href="/" className="text-white">HOME</a>
        <a href="/events" className="text-white">EVENTS</a>
        <a href="/merch" className="text-white">MERCH</a>
        <a href="/contact" className="text-white">CONTACT</a>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Home.js**

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="text-center leading-[150px]">
        <h1 className="text-green-700 -mt-3 font-bold text-[170px] drop-shadow-[0_3px_1px_rgba(255,255,255,0.8)]">
          MAH<br></br>JONG
        </h1>
        <h1 className="text-gray-100 font-bold text-[170px] drop-shadow-[0_3px_1px_rgba(0,0,0,0.8)]">
          SOC<br></br>IAL
        </h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
    <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/events" element={<Events />} />
        <Route path="/merch" element={<Merch />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be much better to post the output HTML and CSS in a functioning demo. This isn't a React or Tailwind issue, so those things are red herrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

It seems that using the `overflow-hidden` feature in Tailwind CSS works. I can now click on the elements in my `Navbar`; see code and photo below.

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="text-center leading-[150px] overflow-hidden">
        <h1 className="text-green-700 -mt-3 font-bold text-[170px] drop-shadow-[0_3px_1px_rgba(255,255,255,0.8)]">
          MAH<br></br>JONG
        </h1>
        <h1 className="text-gray-100 font-bold text-[170px] drop-shadow-[0_3px_1px_rgba(0,0,0,0.8)]">
          SOC<br></br>IAL
        </h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

Thanks,